# CDB command for setting a breakpoint based on a line number

Tags: debugging, windbg, d

Is there a set of CDB commands for setting a breakpoint based on a line number?

It seems that there is no "direct" one. Actually it seems that CDB knowledge is falling into a black hole and it's getting harder and harder to find resources on the Internet.

My CDB setup

> cdb -c "l+*;.lines"

and later I add the source

> lsf mySource.d

Currently I put hard-coded breakpoints with a mixin

```
enum brk = "debug{asm{int 3;}}";
// code
mixin(brk);
```

But it's not a viable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax to break in source line mode, is well explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556902(v=vs.85).aspx) or [here](http://www.windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html#14_tracing), e.g:

> bp `mod!source.c:12`;

And to stop on a particular line:

> g `:20`;