# how to set breakpoint and show source code when using cdb to debug c++ programs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, windbg

why bp main failed?
how to list source code as gdb's list command does?
[image]

this question is not the same as [CDB command for setting a breakpoint based on a line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26775818/cdb-command-for-setting-a-breakpoint-based-on-a-line-number)

seems cdb can be used with windbg, but is that possible to use cdb a bit similar to gdb?

Comment: I would check out the **documentation**. If there is no suitable documentation I would stop using the tool.

Comment: There is a practical limit to what it can do beyond using `******* asterisks *******` to tell you about the problem and the solution.   It isn't going to jump off the screen and slap you in the face :)  Use the debugger built into Visual Studio and a project template to start your project to fall in the pit of success.

Comment: Please don't post pictures, post the text instead. This makes it easier for others to find the question and a potential answer. And that's what makes Stack Overflow useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up symbols in WinDbg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg)

Answer (score 1):

cdb allows 3 different commands to set breakpoints:
bp, bm, and bu

1. bp accepts arguments that are numeric addresses
2. bm accepts arguments that are textual symbols in a module that is already  loaded
3. bu accepts arguments that are textual symbols in modules that may or may not be loaded yet.

To Set a breakpoint at main we can guess Image00390000 is actually hello.exe (Sometimes cdb fails to recover the name you would expect). You can use the command:

```
bm Image00390000!main
```

This assumes that main really is the symbol name, and that symbols are loaded. You can use:

```
lmvm Image00390000 //to check if symbols are loaded
x Image00390000!*main* //lists all symbols that have main anywhere in the name
```